# Why doesn't NRVO work without copy constructor

Tags: c++, nrvo

I'm reading the book *Inside C++ Object Model* and I got things below:
[image]

As I know, NRVO won't call the copy constructor of the class that a function returns.So I don't understand why "This first verison of the program does not apply NRV optimization because of the absence of a copy constructor...".

Comment: Because the standard says so. It will be fixed in C++17.

Comment: @nwp It's mandatory for RVO, but not NRVO, right?

Comment: @nwp   So to active NRVO, the copy constructor must exist even if it's never called?

Comment: Strictly speaking the first example *does* have a copy constructor.  What it doesn't have is a *user defined* copy constructor.  These days, the best way to create a user defined copy constructor would be: `test(const test &t) = default;`

Comment: @TartanLlama Not sure, but I would expect the same behavior for both.

Comment: @Yuhui Yes, for now.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica In practice, as this class is trivial in compiler's terms, the default copy constructor isn't generated in 1st case - from the same book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that the code should work both for compilers that perform the optimization and for those that don't. If the object is copied, obviously the copy constructor must be defined and accessible. So that's the requirement, even for those compilers that might not always use it.

Like said in the comments, C++17 will make the optimizations mandatory and can then relax the requirements.