# Wrap std::thread call function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I would like to control `threads`, so each new issued `thread` will go through my code first.
This way, each new thread issued with `runThread()` in the example below, will first call the function `runInnerThread()` below (in which I do some kind of initializations) and then call the desired function.

I've tried putting something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
void runThreadInner(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) {
    // My initializations...
    __f(__args...);
    // My finishing...
};

template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
bool runThread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) {
    std::thread t(std::bind(&runThreadInner,
                            std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
                            std::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
}

int main() {
    runThread([]() {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "Threading...\n";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error from the compiler which complains about deducing 
 `runThreadInner()` templates

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool runThread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = main()::__lambda0; _Args = {}]’:
main.cpp:43:3:   required from here
main.cpp:27:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, main()::__lambda0)’
        std::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
                                      ^
main.cpp:27:38: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1655:5: note: template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1655:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:27:38: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Func’
        std::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1682:5: note: template<class _Result, class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bindres_helper<_Result, _Func, _BoundArgs>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1682:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:27:38: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Result’
        std::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
```

I tried explicitly defining the template, without any success:

```
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
bool runThread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) {
    std::thread t(std::bind(&runThreadInner<_Callable, _Args>,
                            std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
                            std::forward<_Args>(__args)...));
}
```

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Why the `bind` call? Furthermore, your version of GCC is bordering on ancient, and it doesn't have full C++11 support.

Comment: Also, I do hope your `runThread` have some kind of book-keeping of the threads it starts, so you can `join` them later.

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Callable`, etc.) and names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__f`, etc.) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30968573/4074081 for explanation of std::bind behavior. It would be easier not to use it at all and create thread with `std::thread t(&runThreadInner<_Callable, _Args...>, std::forward<_Callable>(__f), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);` instead.

Comment: Probs with the code: Missing #includes. Simple syntax error (redundant close parenthesis). Identifiers beginning with an underscore and capital letter are reserved for system use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier#228797

Comment: Every line of code in this question, except close braces and most of the body of main, has problems that would make me reject it in a code review.  That is impressive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it was supposed to be a simple example. Maybe I simplified it too much; the actual code is a member function of a class, that's why I need the `bind()`
Yes. I'm not proud of this `gcc` version, hope it will be changed soon.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks. Actually I copied it from `std::thread` - that's why it uses these terms. I won't use it - thanks.

Comment: @Yakk JiveDadson, sorry - I've tried taking out code and change on-the-fly for this example. I've updated the example with the actual code. Thanks.

Comment: Even if `runThreadInner` is a (non-static) member function you don't need to use `std::bind`. Just make sure that the first argument passed to the thread-function is the object. Like e.g. `std::thread myThread(&SomeClass::runThreadInner, this /* or whatever object you want to call runThreadInner on */, ... (rest of arguments) ...)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude doesn't <thread> itself do `std::__bind_simple()` in the `ctor()` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has issues.  I'd reject nearly every line in a code review.

`_Capital` is not legal C++.  `__lower` is not either.  Stop duplicating what system and std headers do, they are allowed you are not.  They are doing it *exactly because you are now allowed* to guarantee their code doesn't overlap with you doing stupid preprocessor things (in any legal way).

```
template<typename Callable>
std::thread runThread(Callable&& f) {
  std::thread t([=]{
    // My initializations...
    f();
    // My finishing...
  });
  return t;
}

int main() {
  auto t = runThread([]() {
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "Threading...\n";
  });
  t.join();
}
```

and if someone wants to bind arguments, let them do it when calling `runThread` themselves.

Comment: Actually it's really simple. It makes `runThreadInner()` redundant because its code can run before and after, in the `lambda` of `runThread()`.

Answer (score 2):

Easy peasy.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
void runThreadInner(Callable&& f, Args&&... args) {
    // My initializations...
    f(args...);
    // My finishing...
};

template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
std::thread runThread(Callable&& f, Args&&... args) {
    std::thread t(&runThreadInner<Callable, Args...>, 
         std::forward<Callable> (f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return t;
}
int main() {
    auto t = runThread([]() {
        std::cout << "Threading..." << std::endl;
    });
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend changing the names leading with two underscores to remove them, since those are reserved for use by the compiler. There be velociraptors.

Comment: @Alexander Hey, I removed the ones beginning with underscore capital. But yeah. I hate leading underscores and camelCase.  Feel free to edit. My job is done here. :-)

Comment: Any variable with consecutive underscores, or a leading underscore follow by a capital letter is reserved for use by the compiler. I hate camelCase too, but at least it won't lead to my code suddenly failing with a new compiler or compiler version.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/4131059

Comment: @Alexander I only knew about the _Capital thing. But then I never do anything remotely like that.  Wanna fix it?

Comment: Wouldn't your solution require copy constructor of `std::thread` before C++17? You initialize return value by an lvalue `t`.

Comment: @Daniel - Every pre-17 compiler I know of elides the copy via return-value optimization.  Feel free to edit if you like.

Comment: @JiveDadson Sure, but I thought NRVO still requires copy constructor to exist. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645939/why-doesnt-nrvo-work-without-copy-constructor.

Comment: @Daniel std::thread has a copy constructor. You done gone plumb circular. It's a vish,

Comment: @JiveDadson It's deleted according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread. But I can compile your case in C++11: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JGL6ldTbAo4uHf0D. What's wrong here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163211/discussion-between-jive-dadson-and-daniel-langr).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing an `#include <functional>` (where `std::bind` is defined).

However, `std::bind` isn't really needed in your case because you have lambda's, which are [better](http://www.gockelhut.com/cpp-pirate/lambda-vs-bind.html) in many ways.

Here's a working example without `std::bind`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>

template <typename F>
struct MyTaskWrapper {
  F f;

  template <typename... T>
  void operator()(T&&... args) {
    std::cout << "Stuff before...\n";
    f(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    std::cout << "Stuff after...\n";
  }

};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void runThread(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  std::thread trd(MyTaskWrapper<F>{std::forward<F>(f)}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  trd.join();
}

int main() {
  runThread([] {
    std::cout << "Threading...\n";
  });
}
```

Output:

```
Stuff before...
Threading...
Stuff after...
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/ONN82025)